# Return false from async Task method

Tags: c#

I am using async Task method. Is there any way to return false from this method. If not how can I handle this scenario?

```
public static async Task Share(MemoryStream streamToEmail)
{
    if(streamToEmail.Length < 10000000)
    {
        await SendEmails();
    }
    else
    {
         //return false;
    }             
}
```

Comment: Change your method to return a `Task<bool>`

Comment: You can change the return type to `Task<bool>` and return `true`/`false` within each branch but you should probably throw an exception instead.

Comment: Take a look at the Task<TResult> class : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless you are planning to also return some boolean in the if-branch. If you do though, you could do it like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> Share(MemoryStream streamToEmail)
{
    if(streamToEmail.Length < 10000000)
    {
        await SendEmails();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }          
}
```